# Saving histogram as jpg

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an array `r`. I want to save the histogram as `A.jpg` but it is not saving anything. Instead, I am getting an error shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

r=np.array([54.3817864 , 50.70031442, 53.63511598, 49.6935623 , 51.80017684,
       52.80854701, 50.18808714, 51.85747597, 47.94544424, 49.59728558,
       53.42810469, 54.3817864 ])

with open("A.jpg", 'w+') as f: 
    r=pd.Series(r)
    r.hist()
    print(r)
```

The error is

```
Sorry, Photos can't open this file because the format is currently unsupported, or the file is corrupted.
```

Comment: That's right. How do I write the histogram to a file?

Comment: you want to store it as screenshot (picture) ? or text ?

Answer (score 0):

Use matplotlib library to save plot as a jpg/png.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r=np.array([54.3817864 , 50.70031442, 53.63511598, 49.6935623 , 51.80017684,
   52.80854701, 50.18808714, 51.85747597, 47.94544424, 49.59728558,
   53.42810469, 54.3817864 ])

plt.hist(r)
plt.savefig("r.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import Image
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

r=np.array([54.3817864 , 50.70031442, 53.63511598, 49.6935623 , 51.80017684,
       52.80854701, 50.18808714, 51.85747597, 47.94544424, 49.59728558,
       53.42810469, 54.3817864 ])

plt.hist(r)
plt.savefig('A.png')
Image.open('A.png').save('A.jpg','JPEG')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to save your picture `A.jpg`m but you're getting the error `Sorry, Photos can't open this file because the format is currently unsupported, or the file is corrupted.` (which I have verified, with your suggested code, you get that error indeed).

If so, try the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r=np.array([54.3817864 , 50.70031442, 53.63511598, 49.6935623 , 51.80017684,
       52.80854701, 50.18808714, 51.85747597, 47.94544424, 49.59728558,
       53.42810469, 54.3817864 ])

r=pd.Series(r)
r.hist()
plt.savefig('A.jpg')  # Or use your own path
```

It should open now. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think using "savefig" will fix this problem:

```
   import numpy as np
   import pandas as pd

   r=np.array([54.3817864 , 50.70031442, 53.63511598, 49.6935623 , 51.80017684,
   52.80854701, 50.18808714, 51.85747597, 47.94544424, 49.59728558,
   53.42810469, 54.3817864 ])

   r=pd.Series(r)
   ax=r.plot.hist()
   print(r)
   ax.figure.savefig("A.png")
```

I don't think you can save it in jpg format through this but you can use "Image" library to convert png to jpg